# How to run certain python program while loop without it running a continuous loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to get a program to ask for the cost 
and then ask for the margin.
I want to be able to repeat it using different amounts of margin.  I have tried different ways but all cause a continuous loop.

Years ago I had this program and it worked and I remember it being pretty simple but I cannot get it now.

I don't remember all that i have tried.  I tried to post some while and if statements i tried on here but it would not let me as i did not know how to format so it would post.  Tried different while statements, if, else statements, continue, break.

```
cost = input('Enter cost: ')
cost = float(cost)
margin = input('Enter margin: ')
margin= float(margin)
while margin != 0:
    print('List equals', cost/margin)
```

Expected it to ask for cost and margin. Then divide cost by margin and give the answer and repeat until i entered stop or margin did not equal a certain amount.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you want to achieve, could you try to rephrase it please?
At the moment you are taking an input for margin and then for as long as the margin is not equal to zero you are printing " 'List equals', cost/margin". Because the value of margin cannot change within the while loop this loop will run forever.

Comment: I would like for it to ask for a cost. ‘Enter cost’.  And say I enter 45.
Then I want it to ask for margin.  ‘Enter margin. And say I enter .65.
Then I want it to divide the cost (45) by the margin (.65) which equals 69.23
Then I want it to print that result as List equals 69.23.
Then I want it to ask for a different margin amount and print the result again.
I would like for this to repeat asking for a different margin amount and giving the result until I stop the loop by entering some predetermined value.  Hope I am being clear.

Comment: Yes that did clear it up, I believe the answers already answer this.

Comment: Well you enter the margin once an then never more, so your margin is always the same causing a loop. Your input statement should be inside the while loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script in its current form reads input and sets it as a float for `cost` and `margin` you then enter your loop if `margin` is not `0`. So assuming you set some non zero value for `margin` you enter the loop. but once you enter the loop you never change the value of `margin` so the condition of the loop forever remains `True`.

Instead you can just run an infinite loop and keep reading for margin on each iteration of the loop. If the value of margin is a non 0 value it will print the result. If the value of margin is 0 the loop will break.

```
cost = float(input('Enter cost: '))
while True:
    margin = float(input('Enter margin: '))
    if margin:
        print('List equals', cost/margin)
    else:
        break
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Enter cost: 10
Enter margin: 2
List equals 5.0
Enter margin: 3
List equals 3.3333333333333335
Enter margin: 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Can you explain why "if margin:" is equivalent to "if margin != 0."?

Comment: Python truthyness of ints and floats etc will consider zero as false and non zero as true. You can check this `print(bool(float(1.4)))` and `print(bool(float(0.0)))`. So in the if expression the boolean value of the expression will be evaluted as `True` when `margin` is a non zero value

Comment: Every day is a school day! Thank you

Comment: this link covers most of the built-in types truthyness https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the below code snippet

```
while True :
    cost = input('Enter cost: ')
    cost = float(cost)
    margin = input('Enter margin: ')
    margin= float(margin)
    print(margin)
    if margin != 0 :   # or what ever value you want it to be
        print('List equals', cost/margin)
        break
    else :
        continue
```

Result :

```
Enter cost: 0
Enter margin: 10
10.0
Enter cost: 20
Enter margin: 20
20.0
List equals 1.0
-----------------
```

Comment: Yes, you are right and I didn't bother to check for condition as I am not sure what would that be used for actually.

Comment: yeah i totally agree......but we know in the world of users anything is possible :)

Comment: After reading the comment explaining better the loop required I don't think this loop works for the intended purposes. The margin should be asked again every time without changing the cost I believe, and the loop stopped when 0 or another predetermined value is entered.